# Transfer time from MySQL database to php countdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently setting up a ban's list for a server I run for the Garry's Mod game.
When I ban someone on the Garry's Mod server it uploads information about the ban onto a MySQL database (as shown below).

[image]

I have noticed that it is writing the 'Length' time as a rather long, complicated number which I have no idea about (apart from the '0' number which is  a permanant ban).
Some how PHP is writing this number into a date and time format:

```
<?php  if ($row['Length'] == '0')
    {
        echo "Permanent";   
    }
    elseif($row['Length'] < time())
    {
        echo "Expired"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo date("g:ia - d M, Y", $row['Length']);
    }
?>
```

Which ends up looking  a little something like this:

[image]

---

This system above is working perfectly well at showing the date when a ban is due to expire.

My main issue is that I would like it to display the time **remaining** until the ban expires in a hour format (eg. Ban expires in: 67 Hours, 29 Minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'complicated number' is Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00). You can for example subtract value of column Length from column Time and calculate from that number of hours and minutes.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for that :)! That should make it possible for me to figure out something.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
// For example, if you have a +2 timezone, you can do this:

$TimeEDITED = gmdate("H:i:s", time() + 7200);

// ... if you do not:

$TimeNONEDITED = gmdate("H:i:s", time());
```